# Reclassify raster based on cell location and value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modis, reclassify

I am working in ArcGIS 10.5 (with the spatial analyst extension); I'm relatively inexperienced but I understand what I am trying to do, just need some help on how to accomplish it.

I am working with MODIS (raster) data. I am trying to reclassify (group) cells in a raster to have the same value if 1) in the same 3x3 neighborhood AND 2) if the difference of their values is less than 6. See picture below for example of what I am trying to do.[image: Raster Reclass Example]

Comment: Yes, I meant a 3x3 neighborbood, I edited my question

Comment: Have a look here please https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73061/neighborhood-analysis-based-on-occurrence-of-value

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; however I am attempting something a little more complicated since I don't care about specific values, but that the difference between all pixels in a group is less than 6 and that they are close to each other in geographic space

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Focal Statistics tool in Spatial Analyst, with Range as the statistic. You could then reclassify this output or possibly use it as a mask involved in reclassifying, depending on how you get the final output values.